# Case-sensitivity issue with Tomcat 8 Resources / PreResources

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, configuration

For starters, we are running Tomcat8, Java8, and Windows Server 2012.

We store images, styles, JavaScript, and other static resources in directories outside of our web application called "shared" and "uploads". To configure this, I create a base context that all apps that looks like this:

```
<Context>
    <Resources>
        <PreResources base="${document.root}\shared" className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet" webAppMount="/shared" />
        <PreResources base="${document.root}\uploads" className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet" webAppMount="/uploads" />
    </Resources>
</Context>
```

And in addition, there is a site specific context that would look like this:

```
<Context docBase="${document.root}\sitename">
</Context>
```

We were noticing that some requests to the shared directory were working and others were not. I figured out that it has to do with the file name casing.  Some files within shared have names that start with lower case letters and some with upper case. Those that have lower case names work fine. So to test a theory, I made two requests to the same file name (one that does not exist), changing only the casing, so I could see the 404 page and see the file path actually being used.

I first requested this URL:

```
{domain}/shared/Base.js
```

The resulting 404 page indicates that Tomcat searched for this path:

```
/shared/base.js
```

I then requested this URL:

```
{domain}/shared/base.js
```

The resulting 404 page indicates that Tomcat searched for this path:

```
/shared/base.js
```

As you can see, no matter what casing I use in the URL, it seems to convert it to lower case. So if I go and rename one of the files that is failing to an all lower case name, everything works. The problem is these are large directories and we are aiming to upgrade our server without a coinciding code update. Also, the content in uploads is submitted by our users and outside of ensuring unique names, we do not alter the file names so casing will continue to be random. Is anyone aware of some attribute or configuration I can use to get Tomcat to use the file name exactly as it is provided in the URL?

Comment: `Typically Windows machines are case insensitive, while Linux machines are case sensitive.` I wonder if its because you are using Windows Server

Comment: RIght, but if anything the case-insensitivity of windows would ensure that these requests are successful. Since they are failing, I can only assume that the case-sensitivity of Java is the issue.  That said, our URLs are on the money as far as using the exact case of the file being requested, but either Tomcat or Java seems to be taking the liberty of lower-casing things for me and inherently causing the failure.

Comment: I disagree it's because of Windows. check http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html `NOTE: This flag MUST NOT be set to false on the Windows platform (or any other OS which does not have a case sensitive filesystem), as it will disable case sensitivity checks, allowing JSP source code disclosure, among other security problems.`

Comment: Maybe I am being obtuse, but I am failing to make the connection between the documentation of that attribute and the issue I am seeing. Can you clarify how Windows lack of case-sensitivity would cause an issue that seems to be clearly caused by the enforcement of case-sensitivity?

Comment: For that matter, the enforcement should actually not be a problem as my URLS all correctly reflect the case of the path and file. The issue is that something is changing the case along the way.

Comment: On Linux file a.txt and file A.txt are different. On Windows file a.txt and file A.txt are not.

Comment: I understand the difference between case-sensitive and case-insensitive. My URL reflects EXACTLY what the case of the entire path is on the server. Case-sensitivity is really not relevant in my opinion. The issue at hand is that the path I indicate in the URL is being changed to lower-case as opposed to being left as-is.

Comment: The URL is being changed because when Tomcat requests the resource from the operating system (Windows) it becomes case insensitive. Use a Linux distro or change all your files to lower case.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but neither of those are options for us currently. I will continue to look into alternate solutions. Keep in mind, we formerly served these files as-is with no issue on Tomcat7 using contexts nested within our host elements directly on the server.xml.  We just created a shared and uploads context for every host.  I was trying to eliminate our use of contexts within the server.xml as recommended by the documentation.  My point is that clearly there are or were scenarios where Tomcat could serve these files in their current state.

Comment: I just wanted to follow up on what I found in case anyone was interested. I finally noticed that we had been using the allowLinking attribute on our base context config in prior installs to work around the case sensitivity. Seems slightly terrible, but now that I know why it used to work and no longer does, I can at least move forward with a fix.

Comment: @Scott Smith so you mean it is impossible with windows and tomcat8 togther?

Comment: @Santhucool As far as I can tell it is not possible to get case insensitivity working with the combination of Tomcat8 and Windows. We are currently still on Tomcat7 for this reason and have not prioritized moving forward as we are shifting to .NET and will no longer have any Tomcat servers at that point.

Comment: @ScottSmith thanks buddy.