# Tomcat gives error with spring boot application deployed

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat9

```
2019-05-15 14:14:39.760 ERROR 5700 --- [io-8080-exec-14] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-14] Exception processing template "Dashboard": An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/Dashboard.html]")
```

On my local computer, there is no problem.

And in the end of log, some other logs:

```
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [layouts/left-nav-bar], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers (template: "layouts/Master" - line 99, col 14)
```

The error comes after here:

```
response.sendRedirect("/myPassword" + viewMyPasswordParam);
```

I used `request.getContextPath()`

instead of that but still error.

> ```
> 2019-05-15 14:44:20.228  INFO 5700 --- [io-8080-exec-14] c.b.g.backend.service.GenericService     : Redirecting to /myPassword
> ```
>
> in onAuthenticationSuccess UNEXPECTED ERROR (this is custom message
>   for /error) 404 could not find page: /error

this is code

```
        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException {
           .
    .
    .
    .
    .
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/myPassword" + viewMyPasswordParam);
  GenericService.logger.info("Redirecting to {} in onAuthenticationSuccess");
//i tried also without request.getContextPath() +
```

is it about thymeleaf? Should i give classpath to thymeleaf?

Comment: Try the solution here, something related to the template resolver: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15777425/springmvcthymeleaf-error-message-is-template-might-not-exist-or-might-not-be/16302768 .... Probably if it is working in the IDE, open the JAR generated and see in which folder the templated are been placed. It sounds like a configuration issue.

Comment: @Brother i look in tomcat, folders are correct. I suspect thymeleaf

Comment: Can it be because we tested on windows but tomcat is  on centos? windows- linux difference? like slashes

Comment: Take a look on this one as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32936108/thymeleaf-template-not-found-with-embedded-tomcat. Sorry, I don't have a windows machine to replicate this issue.

Comment: It is because of case sensitivity. Windows does not care about capitals but linux cares so cant redirect to Test.html for example. now only error is ``Forwarding to error page from request [/add-money] due to exception [Can't find bundle for base name RESULT, locale tr]``

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31862248/case-sensitivity-issue-with-tomcat-8-resources-preresources
i think it is about this.